# How to expose mapped drive to called executable?

Tags: powershell

I want to map a drive in a script and have that mapping visible to an executable that I call.

If I create the mapping with `New-PSDrive`, then call the program with `Start-Process`, the program does not see the mapped drive.

I can use `-Persist` with `New-PSDrive`, which does work, but I then have to un-map it when the process completes.  Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: I shall assume you are not able to use UNC paths ? Is the script not able to call the exe as a wrapper?

Comment: In the called application?  That's correct, it has to be a mapped drive letter.

Comment: Could you use `-Persist` and have the `Start-Process` use wait? When you exe is done then you can dissolve the ps drive?

Comment: @Matt Yes, that does work.  I was hoping to avoid having to unmap, but I guess it's just one additional call.... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think `-Persist` is the only way. And it works for mapped network shares only. To make sure that it's unmapped when the process completes I would do the unmapping in a `finally` block.